# Weblogic debugging remotely

Tags: java, jdeveloper, weblogic11g, ejb-2.x

I am working on middle layer application wher I am using Weblogic server and Jdeveloper.So every time to do small changes I have to deploy the ear file in Weblogic Server and then check the log file to see my changes. Is there anyway where  I can debug this kind of project locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDeveloper has an embedded WebLogic that will allow you to debug your code locally.
It even supports hot-deployment so you don't need to constantly re-deploy.